# Would it be possible to compile and bootstrap GNU?

Tags: gcc, glibc, hurd

A new Guix release came out some time ago. And I got the idea that if I can bootstrap glibc, gcc, and guix to HURD and Mach, I can have a non-Linux GNU system. But I also need some software like bash, emacs, binutils, coreutils, an init system. Do any of those have any system calls that are linux dependent? Would I be able to do it like in LFS?

Comment: Look at Debian Gnu+Hurd https://wiki.debian.org/TheHurd

Comment: I don't want apt-get to be installed, I want Guix to install everything after gcc, glibc, and coreutils

Comment: Linux is just a kernel. If you use HURD/Mach, you've got a non-linux system. (Granted, the other bits and pieces will be from Sys V or later BSD, GNU, Plan 9 and/or other *NIX clones/derivatives, but not Linux itself.)

Answer (score 3):

Some years ago, I created a GNU/Hurd based distribution from scratch. You can still find about it by googling *Bee GNU/Hurd*.

All official GNU software (including the packages you've mentioned) should support Hurd, and most packages actually do. But keep in mind that Hurd is not a drop-in replacement for Linux, so you actually need to cross-compile all packages, or compile them from a native GNU/Hurd system, much in the same way as if you were building your software for another architecture (i.e. building arm software on x86).

That said, I advise you to follow these steps:

- Install Debian GNU/Hurd somewhere (a VM is OK) and get familiar with it.
- Build Guix on said system, and make sure you can actually generate and install packages (you probably will need to make some changes to it).
- Modify Guix to be able to create and manage [SubHurds](https://www.gnu.org/software/hurd/hurd/subhurd.html)
- At this stage, you should be ready for bootstrapping a complete GNU system based on Hurd wherever you want. You just need to configure GRUB properly afterward.

Happy hacking!

Answer (score 3):

[UPDATE] I recently gave a talk at Fosdem about porting Guix to Hurd which you can check here. [guix_to_hurd_fosdem_16](https://fosdem.org/2016/schedule/event/guixhurd/attachments/slides/1219/export/events/attachments/guixhurd/slides/1219/guix_to_hurd_fosdem_20160130.pdf)

I am the one working on the Guix Hurd port. In order to actually use Guix on Hurd, Guix bootstrapping process must first be modified in order to support a GNU/Hurd system. This means Guix must be able to cross-build the hurd version of glibc, Gnumach and Hurd.
 
With this part done, you must build the bootstrapping toolchain using the new glibc and produce the bootstrapping binaries. At this point, the newly built binaries should be copied to a GNU/Hurd system and used to build Guix on that system.

[Guix bootstrapping process](http://www.gnu.org/software/guix/manual/guix.html#Bootstrapping)